# Best translation of "subtle"?

Tags: translation, word-usage

The obvious translation of "subtle" is 「微妙」, but in current usage it seems to carry a bit of a pejorative sense, even implying "dubious". Are there better translations for phrases such as "subtle hint", "subtle meaning" and "subtle colour"?

Answer (score 3):

`微妙` does have a subtext of "dubious" in some contexts, but apparently `微妙な意味` *is* an appropriate translation of "subtle meaning".

When speaking of color, taste or another attribute I would probably use an adjective like `薄い`、`淡い`,  or `かすかな`.

For "subtle hint", Eijiro [offers](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=subtle%20hint) `何げないヒント`.